# how can i add programs to a startup disk

Tags: startup-disk

Hello I am looking for a way to add additional code to a startup disk (beyond the basic iso.)
Specifically looking to add a mud client as i am using a startup disk because my harddive has died
YES I am still mudding in 2013.. or more specifically still looking to play some sort of online game after playing lotro for years before my hard drive crash

Answer (score 0):

check rescuecd it was designed such a way as to make it easy to add other software. beware its build on mine beloved Gentoo, so you will have to do loots of compiling (emerging)

more info in [rescuecd customization](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_personalize_SystemRescueCd)
you may see wether you can use similair method with ubuntuCD from step 4c using apt instead of emerge...

Comment: hrmm was afraid I might have to get in and wade through the command line for a bit, thanks for the prompt answer as it is appreciated.